R, summarize dataframe based on certain columns and put 1 column values into list
I have a large dataframe and I need to summarize based on 3 columns (source, source_detail, information) and values in column year will be put into list, like in Table 2.
My first code is
data %>% group_by(source, source_detail, information) %>% summarise(list_year = unique(year))

but it returns view like in Table 1 below,



source
source_detail
information
list_year




AA
AA-11
Number of women
2019


AA
AA-11
Number of women
2020


AA
AA-22
Number of men
2018


AA
AA-22
Number of men
2019


AA
AA-22
Number of men
2020


BB
BB-33
Percentage of women
2012


BB
BB-33
Percentage of women
2017


BB
BB-33
Percentage of women
2022


BB
BB-44
Percentage of men
2017


BB
BB-44
Percentage of men
2022



while I need output like in Table 2 below



source
source_detail
information
list_year




AA
AA-11
Number of women
2019, 2020


AA
AA-22
Number of men
2018, 2019, 2020


BB
BB-33
Percentage of women
2012, 2017, 2022


BB
BB-44
Percentage of men
2017, 2022



Is it possible to do that in R?
